# Docker dentro de docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tengo un contenedor Docker (php:8.0) que necesito que pueda ejecutar comandos de docker-compose dentro de el.

Ya he montado el volumen docker.sock en el docker-compose pero me falta poder instalar Docker dentro del contenedor para que funcione.

Me podeís orientar?

Gracias

Comment: Si bien se puede, la mayoría de las veces no es necesario. En caso de que sea necesario se puede vincular el docker host con el contenedor pasandole el socket como volumen o bien usar docker in docker https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/

Answer (score 0):

no conozco tu contexto pero para poder hacerlo igual sobre el container host le tienes que montar en el stack de la imagen docker; descargarte una imagen digamos alpine o ubuntu y de ahi incrustarle docker, otra es bajarte una imagen con docker dentro ya pre-instalado y usarla en ambos containers. desde dockerhub si es de testing.

[docker install en Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)